# ROS C++ Custom header not found

Tags: ros, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I created a ROS package with one main cpp file and another my_class.cpp file + my_class.h with some simple cpp code.

As long as I have all files in the src folder of the package, it works fine. As soon as I move the header file to another directory (for example my_package/include/my_package/my_class.h) and change the #include in main to the new path, the header file can't be found (`error: include/sendPgmMarker/my_class.h: No such file or directory`) when I try to compile.

I tried it like in this post: http://answers.ros.org/question/41873/ros-c-custom-class-compiler-and-linker/ but it doesn't work for me.

What changes do I have to make so the header can be found? Sure I could just let the header in the source folder, but I also want to add other external .h and .cpp files that are in other folders than my package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45422/ros-c++-custom-header-not-found/) by [henge266](https://answers.ros.org/users/3352/henge266/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please make sure you have a look at the [support wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/Support) and always tag your question to make sure the right people get notified.

How does your include line look like? I suspect something like:

```
#include <include/sendPgmMarker/my_class.h>
```

You must not specify the `include` subdirectory. It is added to the include path already. Try:

```
#include <senPgmMarker/my_class.h>
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Lorenz sounds like he knows the answer.  But also remember you may need to add a line in your CMakeLists.txt file like this:

include_directories(/your/path/here/)

---

Originally posted by [PerkinsJames](https://answers.ros.org/users/2621/perkinsjames/) with karma: 506 on 2012-10-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-09**:
Good hint. I just want to add that directory `include` at the root of a ros package is already added.